# How to download an image with Selenium for Python？

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, macos-mojave

I open the page with Selenium -

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# login steps are here
driver.get('https://www.example.com/?file=%d' % (FILE_ID) )
```

The page contains `img` element with the source equal to `'https://www.example.com/?file=%d' % (FILE_ID)` value.

Now I would like to save it as GIF.

I tried the following -

```
save_me = ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).key_down('s').key_up(Keys.COMMAND).key_up('s')
save_me.build().perform()
```

-- nothing happens (OSX 10.14.15, latest Chrome).

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
ActionChains(driver).context_click(elem).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
```

-- it opens the context menu, but nothing happens after that.

```
content = driver.page_source
with open('1.gif', 'w') as f:
     f.write(content)
```

-- it creates the file HTML content of the page.

I also can not just get the source value and download the page with `requests`, `urllib` etc. - it requires to emulate all login steps etc.

What else could I try to save the picture?